# Need a regex expression to find an integer contained in double quotes as a property value in JSON file

Tags: json, regex, string, visual-studio-code

I imported a csv file to JSON to use it it Microsoft GRAPH's API. I really wanna use the find/replace feature in VScode to replace the double quotes around the integer with nothing so here's a snip of JSON

```
  {
"displayName": "FirewallRules/12/Action",
"description": null,
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.omaSettingInteger",
"Value": "1",
"omaUri": "./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Firewall/MdmStore/FirewallRules/{firewallrulename}/Action/Type"
```

},

I even tries using my little knowledge of regex to get it done and had some success using this

```
^(.*)"\d{1,2}(.*)"$
```

I wanna ignore "Value", ^(.?)("Value":) and only target "1"
Completely thrown together but I thought it worked, but I cant compensate for the "Value": in front of it. How can I target the Value property's String value containing an integer with regex? Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(\s*"[^"]*"\s*:\s*)"(\d+)"
```

Replace with `$1$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3lPGlr/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\s*"[^"]*"\s*:\s*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more whitespaces, `"`, zero or more chars other than a double quotation mark, `"`, a `:` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more digits
- `"` - a `"` char

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target "2", you can use this regexp

```
^("Value")(.*)("[0-9]+")(.*)$
```

You can try it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: i mean, then u select the group 3 with $3, but im not sure it will work as u want